# Calculate proportions of counts within count categories + dependent on other categorical variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I hope the convoluted title makes sense, but the problem I have is not so easy to get a head around.

The toy dataset lists customer visits along with customer exemption status and visit type:

```
df <- structure(list(Customer = structure(c(8L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Aaron", "Elizabeth", 
"Frank", "John", "Mary", "Pam", "Rob", "Sam"), class = "factor"), 
    Exemption = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Exempt", "Non-exempt"
    ), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Type 1", 
    "Type 2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Customer", "Exemption", 
"Type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

    Customer  Exemption   Type
1        Sam Non-exempt Type 1
2  Elizabeth     Exempt Type 1
3       Mary     Exempt Type 2
4       John Non-exempt Type 1
5       John Non-exempt Type 2
6      Aaron Non-exempt Type 2
7      Aaron Non-exempt Type 2
8        Pam     Exempt Type 2
9        Pam     Exempt Type 2
10       Rob Non-exempt Type 2
11       Rob Non-exempt Type 2
12       Rob Non-exempt Type 1
13     Frank     Exempt Type 1
14     Frank     Exempt Type 1
15     Frank     Exempt Type 2
```

I want to fist categorize customers by the number of visits they made, then within that calculate the proportions of Type1/2 visits, and maybe also break down the results by exemption status, such as the output looks like this:

```
   Number_of_visits  Exemption   Type Proportion
1                 1 Non-exempt Type 1       1.00
2                 1 Non-exempt Type 2       0.00
3                 1     Exempt Type 1       0.50
4                 1     Exempt Type 2       0.50
5                 2 Non-exempt Type 1       0.25
6                 2 Non-exempt Type 2       0.75
7                 2     Exempt Type 1       0.00
8                 2     Exempt Type 2       1.00
9                 3 Non-exempt Type 1       0.33
10                3 Non-exempt Type 2       0.67
11                3     Exempt Type 1       0.67
12                3     Exempt Type 2       0.33
```

I tried a few things with `group_by(Customer, Type) %>% summarise(n())` using `dplyr`, which did not appear to be right.

Comment: Where did the `Customer`'s go in the expected output?

Comment: @mtoto: In the expected output, the Number_of_visits collapses customers to counts, e.g. when `Number_of_visits = 1`, this corresponds to three customers in the list (Sam, Elizabeth, Mary). One of them was Non-exempt and Type 1, so corresponding `Proportion = 1`. Two others were Exempt, one of Type 1 and one of Type 2, so proportions are 0.5 each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` from `dplyr` to count the number of occurrences of `Exemption` and `Type` grouped by `Number_of_visits`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
res <- df %>% group_by(Customer) %>% 
              mutate(Number_of_visits=n()) %>% 
              group_by(Number_of_visits) %>% 
              count(Exemption, Type) %>%
              complete(Type, fill=list(n=0)) %>%
              group_by(Number_of_visits,Exemption) %>% 
              mutate(Proportion=n/sum(n))
```

Notes:

1. First `group_by` `Customer` to compute the number of visits using `n()`.
2. Then `group_by` `Number_of_visits` and use `count` to count the number of occurrences for each value pair for `Exemption` and `Type`. This creates a column named `n` containing this count.
3. Use `tidyr::complete` to fill in any missing value pair for `Exemption` and `Type` with a count of zero.
4. Finally, `group_by` both `Number_of_visits` and `Exemption` to compute the desired `Proportion`.

The result using your data is as expected.

```
print(res)
##Source: local data frame [12 x 5]
##Groups: Number_of_visits, Exemption [6]
##
##   Number_of_visits  Exemption   Type     n Proportion
##              <int>     <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>      <dbl>
##1                 1     Exempt Type 1     1  0.5000000
##2                 1     Exempt Type 2     1  0.5000000
##3                 1 Non-exempt Type 1     1  1.0000000
##4                 1 Non-exempt Type 2     0  0.0000000
##5                 2     Exempt Type 1     0  0.0000000
##6                 2     Exempt Type 2     2  1.0000000
##7                 2 Non-exempt Type 1     1  0.2500000
##8                 2 Non-exempt Type 2     3  0.7500000
##9                 3     Exempt Type 1     2  0.6666667
##10                3     Exempt Type 2     1  0.3333333
##11                3 Non-exempt Type 1     1  0.3333333
##12                3 Non-exempt Type 2     2  0.6666667
```